# Cannot install or uninstall SBT

Tags: sbt, windows-10

Using Windows 10. Trying to install SBT 1.2.1 but cannot because SBT already installed. Trying to uninstall SBT 1.0.2 but it fails.

How do I uninstall SBT 1.0.2 on Windows 10?

Comment: You should provide more details: what exactly have you tried to do, how do you try to install/uninstall sbt, etc.

Comment: I used the Uninstall feature that comes with the .msi download found here [https://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html](https://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html) Had no problem. Once opening the msi download, it asked me if I wanted to upgrade, remove, or install. I choose remove.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure it's going to be there in the control panel under Add/remove programs . If you can't find it with the name SBT it's probably going to be under Simple Build Tool .